# Search for UTF encoded characters using QRegExp

Tags: regex, qt, utf-8, qregexp

I'm trying to check for characters §£¤ using `QRegExp`.

```
QString string = "§¤£";
int res = string.count(QRegExp("[§¤£]"));
```

And the `res` returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your .pro file and set the following:

```
CODECFORSRC = UTF-8
CODECFORTR = UTF-8
```

Then add to your .cpp file:

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
```

That will give you the UTF-8 support for your soruce and internationalization if you need it.